# C# DLL - multiple class objects from Assembly

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll

I have a Assembly (Server.dll) which receives an input string and returns an appended string to it.

I use the dll this way:

```
    using ServerDll;

    ServerDll.Server ob = new ServerDll.Server();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i<10; i++ )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(   ob.GiveAppendedString("Hello")    );
    }
```

Now, I use this assembly in many Asynchronous threads.
So in each thread, I use the code from above.

In different threads, I am able to create the Server object, but, I notice that only one thread is able to use the function GiveAppendedString() in the loop at a time. No two threads are able to use the method exposed by the DLL at the same time in their respective loops.

How can I achieve multi-threaded and concurrent calls to the function GiveAppendedString() from all threads ?

Should I use any multi-threaded apartment model? If yes, are there any weblinks to the steps that I should take as I am novice in this area.

Thanks.

[**UPDATE**] Simplified question: Can a function of an assembly be called by multiple threads ( from an application that references the assembly ) at the same time? If yes, how ?

Comment: Did you write server.dll, or is it third party?

Comment: @Baldrick, Yes, I have written server.dll myself.

Comment: The key is the Server.dll. You should design it to be able to run multithreaded, eventually using the .NET concurrent structures (ConcurrentDictionary, etc.) when needed.

Comment: Thank you all. I was able to resolve it by making the method threadsafe. Appreciate the help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: To answer your updated, simplified question: **Yes**. You need to write the function in a threadsafe manner. This is usually a non trivial task, and you need to make sure that all code called by GiveAppendedString is either threadsafe or put in a lock scope.

That is what locking is for. Wrap the call in a `lock() {...}` scope, e.g.

```
    ServerDll.Server ob = new ServerDll.Server();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i<10; i++ )
    {
        string appendedString;
        lock(ob)
        {
            ob.GiveAppendedString("Hello");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(appendedString);
    }
```

Or, alternatively, make `GiveAppendedString` thread safe if possible.

Comment: I think the OP actually wants the code to run in multiple threads at the same time, but it won't. As far as I can tell, locking achieve the opposite of this.

Comment: That is assuming the call to `GiveAppendedString` needs to be run cuncurrently and the reason for threading is not something external. Anyway, either make the method threadsafe or serialize invocations. There are really no other options.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I somehow feel, there must be a easier way to achieve this such that even legacy VB applications can use it the same way.
Here is the simplified question:

[**UPDATE**] Simplified question: Can a function of an assembly be called by multiple threads ( from an application that references the assembly ) at the same time? If yes, how ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Is your code threadsafe and you are asking about interop issues?

Comment: Thank you all. I was able to resolve it by making the method threadsafe. Appreciate the help provided.

Answer (score 0):

The case depends entirely on the implementation of the `GiveAppendedString()`. If the function is implemented with a lock then it is meant to be running synchronously (or rather not concurrently) for the instance.

For other cases, you can use any [asynchronous techniques](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform concurrent calls. Based on your code, I've provided an example for making concurrent calls here,

```
  Parallel.For(0, 10,
                    i =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ob.GiveAppendedString("Hello"));
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you all. I was able to resolve it by making the method threadsafe. Appreciate the help provided.